# sudo bash -c gave permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, sudo, sudoers

In my linux (centos 7), there are 2 users A (normal user) and B (belongs to wheel group).
I am trying to change User A's .bash_profile file by running the following command with user B.

*./test.sh /home/a/.bash_profile "export something"*

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit

filePath=${1};
content=${2};

result=`sudo grep "$content" $filePath || true`\
if [[ -z $result ]] || [[ $result == \#* ]]; then
    echo "inside the first if";
    sudo sh -c "$(sed '$a\' ${filePath} > ${filePath}.bak)";
    sudo sh -c "$(echo $content >> ${filePath}.bak)";
    sudo rm -fr ${filePath};
    sudo mv ${filePath}.bak ${filePath};
fi
```

However it gave the following error:

*/home/a/.bash_profile.bak: Permission denied*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `$()` operator in `sudo sh -c ...` commands.

When you use this operator for `sed '$a\' ${filePath} > ${filePath}.bak` then `sed` and redirection to file `>` commands are first executed under user **b** rights, which are insufficient for writing. And only after that `sudo sh -c` is performed upon the output of the previous commands.

Use `sudo sh -c "sed ..."`, and `sudo sh -c "echo ..."` instead.

Comment: it says "sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unterminated address regex"

Comment: SED doesn't understand what you want to do. As I can see you are trying to add something in the end of the ${filePath}, but you add nothing.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is that **with user B** add new line char end of A's .bash_profile if **new line char does not exist**. Then add a new content at the end of A's .bash_profile. While doing this back up the original file in case.

Comment: To add a newline use '\$a\' regexp

Comment: Dollar sign should be escaped with \ in the regex above. If you do not escape it bash considers it as a variable `$a` and tries to substitute it with its value.